# How to remove page extension (i.e. /profile.html) with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to remove page extension (i.e. profile.html)  with htaccess ? So if I load www.mysite.com/profile.html I need profile.html to be remove it.

this removes only index.html , if I change it to profile.html it just goes to mysite.com and loads home page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/index.html\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```